# Grayscale image as np.array has shape (100, 80, 3), how?

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently working on a neural network working with grayscale images in form of numpy arrays. For some reason however I occasionally get images with the shape `(.., .., 3)` even though I should only be getting arrays with the shape `(.., ..)`. This means that for some reason some images represent their grayscale color like this: `[100, 100, 100]` instead of just `100`. Is there an effective way to fix this or simply to replace the `[x, x, x]` with an `x`?
Here is the code I use to import images and convert them to be black and white:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(Filepath)
img.convert("1")

print(np.array(img).shape)  # -> (.., .., 3)??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.convert()` method returns a copy of the image, so you will need to assign it to a variable.

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(filepath)
img = img.convert("1")

# Or img = Image.open(filepath).convert("1")
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I really dont want to know why it worked with the majority of images

Comment: the image loader will try to figure out the correct mode, so it's possible that it automatically loaded images as mode `1`. if this solved your problem, you can click the checkmark to mark this as the answer